# Ubuntu Apache2 php7 LAMP server mod_rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I just setup a new AWS EC2 LAMP Stack (using the aws marketplace). the server has php7, Apache2
Now my issue is I would like to use mod_rewrite so that I can go to urls like www.mydomain.com/contact instead of www.mydomain.com/contact.php

However when I go to www.mydomain.com/contact I am getting a file not found error ?? When I go to my domain the main page loads with no issues and if I go to www.mydomain.com/contact.php it works.

so i am not sure what I missed?

If I look at my phpinfo page I see mod_rewrite listed in the loaded modules section. Also my virtualhost file looks like this 9note i replaced my real domain below in this post with "mydomain" obviously i would have my real domain in there.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain_access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
```

In my hosting accounts root directory I have a .htaccess file which has

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Are you accessing your site over HTTP or HTTPS? There's nothing seemingly wrong with what you have posted, providing mod_rewrite is enabled. However, mod_rewrite is not even required here (if all you want to do is have extensionless URLs) - MultiViews does this automatically. And this is already enabled in your server config (except that this is for HTTP-only). However, if you want to do this with mod_rewrite instead, then you should disable MultiViews.

Comment: OK so removing the MultiViews fixed my issue. however if I wanted to use my lets encrypt ssl what changed should I make?

Comment: try certbot... easy to install and setup SSL.

https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions